# How to retrieve QEMU command-line passthrough env var from guest VM

Tags: environment-variables, qemu, libvirt, sles

Below is snippet of my domain xml file which I am using to create SUSE Enterprise Linux Server using virsh. I want to know how I can retrieve this env value ***TEST_KEY*** from my guest VM after log in.

```
<qemu:commandline>
<qemu:env name='MY_KEY' value='TEST_KEY'/>
</qemu:commandline>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've mis-interpreted what this XML configuration does I'm afraid. It sets this environment variable when QEMU is executed on the host OS. It is not exposed inside the guest OS at all.

Comment: Yes I might be misinterpreted how this  qemu:env work and you have any idea how I can pass env vars from domain xml to guest OS?

Comment: There is no mechanism for doing that